# Right Speaker is not working

Tags: speakers

My speakers are working fine before 20.04 latest update. I use Dell Inspiron 5558 laptop. I tried but I couldn't find any solution. Does anyone know how to fix it?.

Comment: Using 20.04.2 LTS with updates today and both the speakers on my PC are working fine through `Settings` > `Sound`

Comment: Thanks, bro It's working. Maybe a glitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparatively useless answer but:
You might wanna boot an older/different version from USB-stick to confirm it's a software issue and it's not just epic bad timing of your speaker breaking...

Also: Do you get both sides using headphones?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

After the completion of the update, it works fine. The quality of the sound slightly increased better.
Increase in performance also.